# jQuery working in IE, but not in Chrome/Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, error, content-editor-web-part, jquery-ui

I've been trying to fix this bug for more than 10 hours, but I just can't figure out how to fix it.

When **using Internet Explorer 11, I don't get this bug**, when using Edge or Chrome I get it. If I clear the history and cache **the error doesn't appear the first time the page loads**. But if I open the page again, the error appears.

[image]

Line 94 points to this:

```
$("#" + divname + "no").html("&nbsp;[" + $("#" + divname).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records') + "]");
```

which is inside a `loadGrid` function:

```
function loadGrid(listname, query, divname, colnames, colmdodel,showSubGrid,subGridFunction) {

    $("#" + divname).jqGrid({
        datatype: function () { loadGridData(listname, query, divname); },
        colNames: colnames,
        colModel: colmdodel,
        subGrid: showSubGrid,
        subGridRowExpanded: subGridFunction,
        height: "100%",
        loadonce: true,
        rowNum: 9999,
        gridComplete: function () {

            $("#" + divname + "no").html("&nbsp;[" + $("#" + divname).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records') + "]");
            //if (divname == "gridmy") { updatePositionCols(); }

            $("#" + divname).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'local' });

        },
        ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
            //onDoubleClickGrid(rowid, iRow, iCol, e, divname, listname);
        }
    });

    $("#" + divname).jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
        autosearch: true,
        stringResult: false,
        searchOnEnter: true,
        defaultSearch: "cn",
    });

    $("#" + divname + "action").height("40px");
    $("#" + divname + "action").html("<button style=\" font: bold 12px/1 'Segoe UI','Segoe',Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;\"  type=\"button\" class=\"skip\" onclick=\"exportToExcel('" + divname + "');\">" + imgExcel + "&nbsp;Export To Excel</button>");
}
```

On the internet there were a lot of suggestions to check how jQuery is used.

On SharePoint I have a Content Editor on the page where I have this inside:

```
<div class="ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-embedcode ms-rte-embedil ms-rtestate-notify" contenteditable="false">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/tools/scripts/apps/cpc.js"></script> 
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js" integrity="sha256-siFczlgw4jULnUICcdm9gjQPZkw/YPDqhQ9+nAOScE4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-KM512VNnjElC30ehFwehXjx1YCHPiQkOPmqnrWtpccM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/5.4.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-de.min.js" integrity="sha256-RjiiXuat7O4vsxiSYStIKXNPPY/VBgHPVtpfm6d5vqw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/5.4.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" integrity="sha256-FnArI+EzP1sml6lP7y0hYGQ6TltZA5+FfqpRBRUnMOE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/tools/scripts/apps/3rdParties/startPage3rdParties.js" unselectable="on"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/tools/scripts/tools/jqgrid/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/tools/Scripts/tools/date.js" unselectable="on"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/tools/Scripts/tools/jquerymap/dist/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/tools/Scripts/tools/jquerymap/dist/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/tools/scripts/apps/3rdParties/gridhandling.js"></script> 
   <link href="/tools/scripts/apps/3rdParties/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
   <link href="/tools/Scripts/tools/jquerymap/dist/jqvmap.css" rel="stylesheet"/></div>
<p>
   <br/>
</p>
```

I've tried a lot of combinations to check if it's related to the order, but the error still appears. Used newer versions of jQuery, used the non-compressed versions etc. all without success.

This is what it looks like when it works (on Microsoft Edge):

[image]

This is what it looks like when it doesn't work:

[image]

In the code I tried using

`var jQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);`

and then replaced every `$` - but still no fix.

When I delete the cache the site works only once and `$.fn.jqGrid` is also defined on the console:

[image]

When opening the site on a new tab the console tells that `$.fn.jqGrid` is `undefined`.

I'm using SharePoint (if that's relevant).

Any kind of tip/help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Is Minimal Download Strategy enabled on the site?

Comment: @DylanCristy It was enabled, yes. (Didn't even know such a thing existed!) The problem stills appears after disabling it though

Comment: You can check this answer  it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319428/jquery-is-working-in-ie-but-not-in-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the codepart that didn't work like this solved the problem:

```
$.getScript("/tools/scripts/tools/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid_5_3_0.min.js", function () {
     $("#" + divname + "no").html("&nbsp;[" + $("#" + divname).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records') + "]");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    ...
    $.getScript("largejs.js");
});
```